# PHP returning application/octet-stream instead of javascript for JSONP

Tags: javascript, php, apache, callback, jsonp

I have the following PHP code

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
{
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
else
{
  $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
$data = array('ip'=>$ip); 
echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($data).');';
?>
```

and the following Javascript code

```
<script>

function getip(json) {
    alert("It works!");
    document.getElementById('ipaddr').value = json.ip;
}
//http://ip.jsontest.com/
</script>

<script src="http://myserver.com/?callback=getip">  </script>
```

When I use `http://ip.jsontest.com/` or `http://jsonip.appspot.com` or `http://jsonip.com` in the callback, it returns the IP value as expected.

When I visit `http://myserver.com/` it displays `({"ip":"123.123.123.123"});` as expected.

However, when I use `<script src="http://myserver.com/?callback=getip">  </script>`, it displays nothing.

The Chrome console says `400 Bad Request` and `application/octet-stream` for `http://myserver.com/?callback=getip` but `application/javascript` for `http://ip.jsontest.com/?callback=getip`, `http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=getip`, `http://jsonip.com?callback=getip` so I believe the problem is that it's not return the correct type of data.

I have tried disable `output_buffering` and restarting the server (A QNAP NAS running Apache) but it's not working.

Comment: The correct MIME type for JSON is `application/json`, maybe Chrome doesn't understand  `application/javascript`. Edit: By the way, `text/html` should also just work.

Comment: @JochemKuijpers: JSONP is not JSON.  JSONP should be `application/javascript`.

Comment: So, what happens if you visit `http://myserver.com/?callback=getip` in your browser?  Not in the script tag, but in the address bar.

Comment: @RocketHazmat It shows `({"ip":"123.123.123.123"});` with the brackets around it but the other sites only show everything inside the brackets (braces)

Comment: So, when you go to `http://myserver.com/?callback=getip`, you see `({"ip":"123.123.123.123"});`?  What happened to `$_GET['callback']`?  You should be seeing `getip({"ip":"123.123.123.123"});`.  This is why it's not working.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Oh is that why... Do you have any idea why the callback parameter is not being set?

Comment: @Jack: Dunno.  Server config or something?  Is `http://myserver.com/` getting redirected somehow (like with a `.htaccess`)?  How is the call to `http://myserver.com/` being sent to the PHP script?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Actually nm, I was mistaken.  It does return `getip({"ip":"123.123.123.123"});`.  So my only conclusion is that the server is not setting the header correctly.